# Completion Block for 360 Degree Rotation Animate With Duration

Tags: ios, swift

Hi I am trying to get this to complete the 360 turn on an infinite loop by using the completion recalling the function.  Everything seems to be working but the function is not called again a second time.  I tried many types of completion formats which all print it is called however the actual recalling of the function is not working.  Am I missing something? Thanks

```
    func rotateBackground()
    {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(5, delay: 0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.backgroundImage.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((180.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0)

            }, completion: { (value: Bool) -> Void in
                self.rotateBackground()
            }
        )


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the method again in your completion block, try adding ".Repeat" into your animation options.

Comment: I tried the .Repeat and what it does is take the image and revert it back to the rotation 0 degrees and go back to 180 and not continue on from 180 to 360.  Is there something else i need to do?